# Begin search on first keypress in jQuery Chosen

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am using [jQuery chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) as an alternative to normal html 'select'. I went through its documentation and also its source files but couldn't achieve what I wanted.

My database is very large(50K entries). I populate the select tab with this data.
When I click on this select it takes ages to drop down.

[Here is the demo of my project.](http://medexcel.comeze.com/assign_distributor.php)

Can I achieve the following in chosen.

-When I click select tag It should not show all the data initially.

-When I enter at least one charachter, results should get displayed.

If its not possible, is there an alternative to chosen which would solve the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking for is an autocomplete control, not a pretty-fied select box.

Comment: That control is super slow by the way...

Comment: @HanletEscaño - That's the issue I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Combobox version of jQuery Autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

It will help you make your control work like dropdown and autocomplete as well.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: That was exactly how I wanted it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

this might be what you need:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

(or pretty close at least)

## try this:

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  "<option value='".$row['FirstName'] . "' /> "
  echo "<br>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Datalist not supported in safari. Any jQuery alternative?